# Convert image url into image bye in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
for (int i = 0; i < (DataTable)ViewState["Table_RemarksDetails"]).Rows.Count; i++)
                    {

                  string url = Image1.ImageUrl;

                   Byte[] imgByte = GetBytesFromUrl(url);

                        obj_ICCommon.Userid = username;
                        obj_ICCommon.Modules = "Transfer-TO";
                        obj_ICCommon.Invoiceno = TransferNo;
                        obj_ICCommon.Comments = ((DataTable)ViewState["Table_RemarksDetails"]).Rows[i]["Comments"].ToString();
                        //obj_ICCommon.Image = imgByte;
                        string Result = obj_ICCommon.funinsertRemarks();
                        fun_InsertRemarksImage(TransferNo, imgByte, ((DataTable)ViewState["Table_RemarksDetails"]).Rows[i]["Comments"].ToString());

                }   

  static public byte[] GetBytesFromUrl(string url)
    {
        byte[] b;

        System.Net.HttpWebRequest myReq = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        System.Net.WebResponse myResp = myReq.GetResponse();

        Stream stream = myResp.GetResponseStream();
        //int i;
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            //i = (int)(stream.Length);
            b = br.ReadBytes(500000);
            br.Close();
        }

        myResp.Close();
        return b;
    }
```

This code throws an exception url not recognized. My url is in format like "data://image.png" . What to do ? Anyone lets you know. I am struggle in this past 2 days.

> I just want to convert the url into byte

. If my code is wrong or any other way is possible to convert url into byte. Please comment me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Skimming through (this)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme] Wikipedia link, it seems that the URL you need to return, needs to have the `data` resource identifier. To actually load an image you would need to have some other format, like `http`, `https` or `file`.

Comment: @npinti  in case i have to put other format like htp,https the image is not loaded . Thats why am putting this format data

Comment: If it's a data uri, it should have the image appended in base64, so you'd want to parse the data uri for the base64 string, then convert that to bytes with `Convert.FromBase64String`

Comment: If your format example, `data://image.png` is a complete example however, then you don't have anything other than a file name, which isn't going to be enough to go off of.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn a `data` URI into a byte image, your input string is not sufficient. Given the following sample data URI:

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
```

You would need to:

1. Trim the `data:` string from the front.
2. Split by the `;` character to get the image format and encoding type.
3. If the encoding type is `Base64`, you would need to use the data obtained in (2) to decode the image string back into a byte array.

If on the other hand, you want to change the image `data.png` into its corresponding base64 representation, then you would need to make some changes to your code:

1. Decide what URL's you are going to be reading. If they are web, such as `http` and `https`, then your code should be good since you are dealing with web requests. If they are actual file paths, you would need to handle the `file` URI, so your code would be slightly different.
2. One that you will have your file, you would need to load it as a byte array.
3. Create a string with the following: `data:image/png;base64,`.
4. Append the base64 representation of the byte array you got in step 2.

Comment: How to trim the data: and why i split ; @npinti

Comment: @divikdiya: So that you get to the encoded string. I am assuming that the structure of the string is as the one I specified.